# How to show checkbox as checked in SAP B1 UserForm?

Tags: c#, sapb1

```
namespace BordroPlus
{
    [FormAttribute("BordroPlus.Puantaj", "Puantaj.b1f")]
    class Puantaj : UserFormBase
    {
        SAPbouiCOM.Form oForm;
        .....

        CheckBox4.ValOn = "Y";
        CheckBox4.ValOff = "N";
        oForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("UD_4", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1);
        CheckBox4.DataBind.SetBound(true, "", "UD_4");

       // this sets the checkbox to checked
        oForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("UD_4").Value = "Y"; `I have created an user form and tabcontrol in the form. Then i create a check box in the tab.
```

How can i start the checkbox as checked?

Thats my code.
I am using C# in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Teta's answer,you would initialize ValOn and ValOff like this:

```
    CheckBox0.ValOn = "Y";
    CheckBox0.ValOff = "N";
```

You also need to setup a DataSource for the Checkbox for it to work properly:

```
    oForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("CheckboxDS", BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1);
    CheckBox0.DataBind.SetBound(True, "", "CheckboxDS");

    // this sets the checkbox to checked
    oForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("CheckboxDS").Value = "Y";
```

Comment: I have a userForm that named "Puantaj". What can i write to instead of "oForm" ? @Overhed

Comment: when i write like this it give me an error "the ptForm already exist". ptForm is my form's uniqieid @Overhed

Comment: Have you tried tracing the code? Not sure why you're getting that error. Trace it and tell us what line is giving you the issue.

Comment: Now it gave me SystemNullReferenceException

Comment: Ok, again, where? Trace your code, look at what line is throwing the Exception and relay the information.

Comment: It gives at here  oForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("CheckboxDS", BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1); for "oForm"

Comment: Are you initializing your oForm object after this line? SAPbouiCOM.Form oForm;

Comment: No i am not, how can i do this?

Comment: Ahhh... Ahmet, you need to look at the SDK samples, you have too many gaps in your knowledge at the moment. Just about all the SDK samples will show you how to do this. Look at the directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples\COM UI\CSharp in your Dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the valOn and valOff when creating your checkbox